# Why is semi-norm special and preferred?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

One difference between [semi-norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seminorm) and norm is:

"It is possible for $\|v\| = 0$  for nonzero v, $\|\cdot\|$ being semi-norm"

I see some papers, and they use semi-norm directly.

Why is semi-norm better than norm?

Any simple example or concrete example?

Comment: Seminorms allow us to maintain distinctions between points that are not distinguished by the seminorm. This comes up in certain situations, for example if $f$ and $g$ are measurable functions and $f=g$ a.e. then $\| f - g \|_1 = 0$ even if $f \neq g$. It is often convenient to define a seminorm and then quotient out all points which have seminorm zero. Since in the new space all the points which had seminorm zero now *are* zero, the new space is a normed space. Referring to the same example as before, this is how the $L^p$ spaces are constructed.

Comment: I unfortunately can't say much more than that without more context.

Comment: It may be that they are mentioned not because they are better but because the arise naturally.  One might find a seminorm and then declare $v_1$ and $v_2$ equivalent if the seminorm of $v_1-v_2$ is $0$, and then work with a quotient space that has a norm.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A common use is in topologizing certain function spaces. For example, let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}$ be open. We want a topology on $C^\infty(\Omega)$ the collection of smooth functions. Intuitively we'd like convergence $f_n \to f$ to imply the convergence locally of all derivatives. So what we do is we use a family of semi-norms to do it. $\|f\|_{K,n}$ is the sup norm of $f^{(n)}$ over the compact set $K$. There's no sensible reason to "quotient" by polynomials, so we have to admit the possibility that a non-zero function have non-zero $n^{th}$ derivative. (also a smooth function can be zero on some compact subset without being zero).

This becomes important in defining distribution spaces for PDE's

Comment: Good to know. But is there a possible way to find these non-zero functions with zero semi-norms so that we can factor out and have a norm on some quotient space?

Comment: The same wouldn't be true in the general case where you put some semi-norm on the partials in higher dimensions, but over $\mathbb{R}$, anything that has $n^th$ derivative zero on some $K$ will be a polynomial of degree at most $n$ on connected components of $K$. But why would we want to quotient by things that look like polynomials locally?

Comment: so there is no way to go global?

Comment: We want the semi-norms to all be defined, but we often are working on open subsets where if we just took the sup norm of the nth over the whole thing it might be undefined for some functions. And from the distribution space view we want some way to talk about $C^\infty$ as a whole topologically, because it pairs off by integration with $C_0^\infty$ which gives an inclusion of smooth functions into distributions.

Comment: This is related to locally convex topological vector spaces: a TVS is LC if and only if its topology is generated by a family of seminorms.